# Retrive specific data from firebase in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Hi i have this structure of firebase database:

[image]

I need to retrive the specific data: Shane/DatiUtente/Password from the database and add it into a string var

please someone can tell me how is possible.

Sorry for my english if is bad i'm italian :)

Answer (score 1):

You are going to need to parse through your database and retrieve the value you want. It would be something like this:

```
 //At the top of your class set an empty variable like this:

          var pass = String()

     //Say for example you want to display that password to a label on your storyboard
                @IBOutlet weak var passLbl: UILabel!

//Inside your viewDidLoad function you would want to add this:
       DBRef.child("Shane").child("DatiUtente").child("Password").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snaps) in
     if let dictionary = snaps.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
      self.passLbl.text = dictionary["pass"] as? String }
```

// IF you want it to the string as you asked
replace the self.passLbl.text with the empty pass variable you created at the top.

Comment: Thanks i solve the problem by using something like, you helped me much, thanks again :)